# Process payments with paypal into two accounts

Tags: paypal

I would like to know if there is any way of receive a payment into two different accounts. The amount would be splitted into two using different bank accounts.

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. How you implement this depends on the PayPal product you're using however.

I'm assuming you're talking about a single transactions with $x going to one account, and $y going to another account, right?

## 1:

With PayPal Express Checkout, you can specify the `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID` parameter in your `SetExpressCheckout` API call.
For example, you could have the following request:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=firstemail@domain.tld
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=2.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=secondemail@domain.tld
```

This would create a transaction with $1 to your first receiver, and $2 to your second.
This is also referred to as 'parallel payments' with Express Checkout.

For runnable examples you can test in our sandbox environment, I suggest taking a look at the [following guide on our developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/).